# CSS rule isn't applied

Tags: css, django

I have the following CSS:

**workoutcal.css**:

```
.errorlist{
    color:red;
}
```

the following base template:

**base.html**:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}Default Title{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/workoutcal.css' %}">
</head>
<body>

{% block content %}{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}{% endblock %}

<div class="hidden" id="hidden">
{% block hidden %}{% endblock %}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and the following template that inherits from it:

```
{% extends "workout/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Register new user</h1>
<form action="/workoutcal/register/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                {{ field.label_tag }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                {{ field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                {{ field.errors }}
            </div>
        </div>

    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

If there are any errors, they will lead to `<ul>` elements with the `.errorlist` class being rendered in the browser:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <label for="id_username">Username:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input type="text" name="username" value="sahand" maxlength="150" required id="id_username" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <ul class="errorlist"><li>A user with that username already exists.</li></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the text in this `ul`-list to be red, as I've tried to make it with the rule in my CSS. The CSS is included in the rendered HTML in the browser:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Default Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/workoutcal.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

It's in the last `link`-tag. It is also the last CSS of the ones in the `head` element. Why isn't the error text made red?

Comment: did you try to use color: red !important; ? it's kind of a hack but maybe it works

Comment: Can you use the dev tools to see why the colour is not being applied?

Comment: Are you sure the CSS file is actually being loaded? Can you see it if you go directly to that URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel Roseman wisely suggested to go to the URL of the CSS. I did, and saw that my CSS rule to make the error text red wasn't there. I saved it once more in my text editor and reloaded it, and it was suddenly in the CSS file loaded through the browser, and the text became red. Seems like I didn't save it, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
        <ul><li class="errorlist">A user with that username already exists.</li></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be because other CSS declarations are overriding it. Potentially there’s a declaration on `li` elements that makes them black.

If that is a case, change your css to:

```
.errorlist li {
    color:red;
}
```